# How to import class from applied Gradle file?

Tags: gradle

My `build.gradle` file has:

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/dependencies.gradle"
```

and `build.gradle` can:

```
import com.example.CustomPlugin
```

but doing the same from within `dependencies.gradle` emits:

> startup failed:
>     script 'dependencies.gradle': 7: unable to resolve class com.example.PlatformJava8FixPlugin

What's needed to be able to import the class from `dependencies.gradle`?

Comment: Where is `com.example.PlatformJava8FixPlugin` defined?

Comment: From someplace accessible to `build.gradle`. The import works from `build.gradle`.

Comment: What I mean is whether it is defined in your code in another build script, or is it an external class? Also, in case it is defined in another script does this script located under the buildSrc folder or under some other folder?

Comment: It's defined in a plugin that's automatically applied by our wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

com.example.PlatformJava8FixPlugin must be at the classpath of your build. So if you top level build file has some special buildScript-dependencies like:

```
 buildscript {
     dependencies {
        classpath("com.example:gradle-plugin:+")
     }
 }
```

Your *dependencies.gradle* need that too.

Comment: I think I have a better understanding now. When `build.gradle` does an `apply` to the file `dependencies.gradle`, it, in effect if not in implementation, executes it in a subshell and that subshell doesn't inherit the classpath of `build.gradle`. Is this correct?